# need to rate with stars different things in one Wordpress post/page

Tags: wordpress

I´m using Wordpress to develop a blog, and I need to rate things using a 5 star rate.
I saw many different plugins that rate pages and posts. But, besides posts and pages, what I need is to rate several things in the same post/page. 
I have a list of links, where users cane rate each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure plugins can do what you want to accomplish. And even if you used the API, it would be difficult to achieve your desired result. In order for things to get rated, they must be created as a post/page because of the post meta table on the back end.